# Print variables coming to model's methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, console

Having following code:

```
 class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

     before_create :do_process

     def do_process
         #I want to print here everything that came to this method 
         self.my_stuff = my_stuff
     end
```

Say we have  model with `name` and `description` attributes and
 I'm going into console and enter something like

`MyModel.create! name: 'test', description: 'test'`

So how can I view what arguments passed to method `do_process`?

Comment: nothing is coming to your method there, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I don't really understand your question - you want to check what arguments are passed into your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what you really want is to see the attributes of the object as it enters the `do_process` method. For that, you can use the `attributes` method:

```
def do_process
  $stderr.puts attributes
  self.my_stuff = my_stuff
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
def do_process(*args)
  puts args
  # body of method
end
```